# How do I drag and drop without displaying picture I am dragging?

Tags: java, javafx, drag-and-drop, fxml

I am setting up a battleship game where I want be able to set the ships up on the game board by dragging an `ImageView` of the battleships onto buttons in a grid. I have the following code to set up all the handling of the dragging and dropping so far:

```
        private void configureDragAndDrop(ImageView image) {

        image.setOnDragDetected(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){

            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                Dragboard db = pictureOne.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);

                ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
                content.putImage(pictureOne.getImage());
                db.setContent(content);

                event.consume();
            }

        });



        for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
            if(target.getId() != null) {
                target.setOnDragOver(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data is dragged over the target */
                        /* accept it only if it is not dragged from the same node 
                         * and if it has a string data */
                        if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                                event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
                            /* allow for moving */
                            event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
                        }

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
            if(target.getId() != null) {
                target.setOnDragEntered(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                    /* the drag-and-drop gesture entered the target */
                    /* show to the user that it is an actual gesture target */
                         if (event.getGestureSource() != target &&
                                 event.getDragboard().hasImage()) {
                             target.setStyle("-fx-background-color: pink");
                         }

                         event.consume();
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
            if(target.getId() != null) {
                target.setOnDragExited(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* mouse moved away, remove the graphical cues */
                        target.setStyle("-fx-background-color:blue");

                        event.consume();
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
            if(target.getId() != null) {
                target.setOnDragDropped(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data dropped */
                        /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                        boolean success = false;
                        if (db.hasImage()) {
                           target.setStyle("-fx-background-color:green");
                           success = true;
                        }
                        /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
                         * transferred and used */
                        event.setDropCompleted(success);

                        event.consume();
                     }
                });
            }

        }

        for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
            if(target.getId() != null) {
                target.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
                    public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                        /* data dropped */
                        /* if there is a string data on dragboard, read it and use it */
                        Dragboard db = event.getDragboard();
                        boolean success = false;
                        if (db.hasImage()) {
                           target.setStyle("-fx-background-color:yellow");
                           success = true;
                        }
                        /* let the source know whether the string was successfully 
                         * transferred and used */
                        event.setDropCompleted(success);

                        event.consume();
                     }
                });
            }
        }

        image.setOnDragDone(new EventHandler<DragEvent>() {
            public void handle(DragEvent event) {
                /* the drag and drop gesture ended */
                /* if the data was successfully moved, clear it */
                if (event.getTransferMode() == TransferMode.MOVE) {
                    pictureOne.setOpacity(0.0);
                }
                event.consume();
            }
        });




    }
```

As of right now the drag is working for the most part, except for the `setOnDragDone` section which isn't changing the color to green (but I will work on that later).

My question is that when I start the drag is there anyway to set the size of the image that is being dragged (rather than the full size of the original image showing up). If not, am I able to still drag the image but not show the image that is being dragged, and just change the color of the target.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly a very quick suggestion, why do you have five separate "for" loops to set different drag handlers for same set of nodes. You can do all in a single for loop only.

```
for(Node target: playerGrid.getChildren()) {
   if(target.getId() != null) {
      target.setOnDragOver(..);
      target.setOnDragEntered(..);
      target.setOnDragExited(..);
      target.setOnDragDropped(..);
      target.setOnDragDone(..);
   }
}
```

Coming to the actual question, to resize the image and set in the dragboard you can use the 'snapshot' feature. Check the below code to set resized image in dragboard.

```
double displaySize = 150;
double dragSize = 50;
ImageView pictureOne = new ImageView(new Image(ImageDragDemo.class.getResourceAsStream(imgName)));
pictureOne.setFitHeight(displaySize);
pictureOne.setFitWidth(displaySize);
pictureOne.setOnDragDetected(event -> {
    Dragboard db = pictureOne.startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.ANY);
    ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
    // Resizing the image to required size before taking the snapshot.
    pictureOne.setFitHeight(dragSize);
    pictureOne.setFitWidth(dragSize);

    content.putImage(pictureOne.snapshot(null,null));

    // Resetting the image to initial size after taking the snapshot.
    pictureOne.setFitHeight(displaySize);
    pictureOne.setFitWidth(displaySize);
    db.setContent(content);
    event.consume();
});
```

If you are not interested in implementation to revert the imagesize, you can create a new ImageView and take a snapshot.

```
ImageView dragImage = new ImageView(pictureOne.getImage());
dragImage.setFitHeight(dragSize);
dragImage.setFitWidth(dragSize);
content.putImage(dragImage.snapshot(null,null));
```

To the other question of not showing the image, I think you can set any STRING content and verify it instead of using event.getDragboard().hasImage(). Something like..

```
// Instead of content.putImage(..) use
content.putString("DRAG_IMAGE");
..
// And instead of checking using event.getDragboard().hasImage() use
event.getDragboard().hasString() && event.getDragboard().getString().equals("DRAG_IMAGE")
```